# Mysql select query "order by" not returning results as expected

Tags: mysql

We have a clients' master table. I want to show list of all clients in a dropdown list.
But, I want a client namely "General" at top of the list. I used following query.

```
SELECT * FROM `client` ORDER BY FIELD(`CLIENT_NAME`,'General')
```

Query returns results but General is not the first record in the result list, as expected.
I tried few more queries but no luck.

```
SELECT * FROM `client` ORDER BY FIELD(`CLIENT_NAME`,'General') ASC

SELECT * FROM `client` ORDER BY `CLIENT_NAME`,FIELD(`CLIENT_NAME`,'General')

SELECT * FROM `client` ORDER BY `CLIENT_NAME`,FIELD(`CLIENT_NAME`,'General') ASC
```

I repaired, optimized, checked the table but no difference.
All above queries return results. So, I am not sure, how to debug this?

Is the problem related to MySQL version on the server? or the problem is in MySQL itself?
We have MySQL 5.0 on the server.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: `ORDER BY CLIENT_NAME != 'General'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, what you need is:

```
SELECT * FROM `client` ORDER BY FIELD(`CLIENT_NAME`,'General') DESC, `CLIENT_NAME`
```

This will order first by whether the name is "General", then by client name.

Comment: Thanks a ton, MrZebra :)
Worked like a charm !!